# How do I use Anaconda packages in PyCharm without having to reinstall them?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, anaconda

I mainly use Jupyter Notebooks/Lab through Anaconda and typically install needed packages using pip. However, I've recently started using PyCharm and have been unable to access these packages despite using a Conda environment as my project interpreter and instead have to individually reinstall each of the packages through PyCharm.

These are my settings when creating a new project in PyCharm:

New environment using Conda

Location: C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\envs\untitled

Python Version: 3.8

Conda executable: C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe

I've also added the following three paths to my environment variables:

- ...\anaconda3\Scripts
- ...\anaconda3
- ...\anaconda3\Library\bin

Is there a way for me to access the Anaconda packages without reinstalling them for PyCharm? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't checked it out already, Anaconda has some good documentation on how to use PyCharm with an Anaconda environment that you can check out [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/pycharm/#:%7E:text=Using%20PyCharm%C2%B6%20PyCharm%20is%20an%20IDE%20that%20integrates,supports%20creating%20virtual%20environments%20for%20Python%20with%20conda.).

You will probably want to use an `Existing Environment` rather than create a new one and will have to make sure you point your Conda path to the existing executable (C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe). You should then be able to select the existing environments you have setup in the `Interpreter` drop down.

[image: des]

Comment: Thanks for the help! I had to add an interpreter with C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\python.exe as the interpreter and it immediately loaded all of the packages. Nice username by the way.

Comment: Hahaha, I just noticed yours too! Great minds think alike :)